# The problem of displaying values ​in a ScrollView when taking the values ​from an array in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I'm facing a strange problem and I can't quite manage to solve it.
Initially I define 1 object with arrays and an array of keys
After that I have a function where I retrieve some data

```
const data: object = {
        [MEDICAL]: [],
        [INSTITUTIONAL]: [],
        [OTHER]: []
    };

    const keys: string[] = Object.keys(data);

    (async () => {
        try {
            const personalInfo: string[] = await etherContract.getMyInfo();
            personalInfo.forEach((info: string) => {
               const parsedInfo: object = JSON.parse(info);
               // @ts-ignore
                if (parsedInfo.documentType === MEDICAL) {
                   // @ts-ignore
                    data[MEDICAL].push(parsedInfo);
                    // @ts-ignore
                } else if (parsedInfo.documentType === INSTITUTIONAL) {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    data[INSTITUTIONAL].push(parsedInfo);
                    // @ts-ignore
                } else if (parsedInfo.documentType === OTHER) {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    data[OTHER].push(parsedInfo);
                }
            });
        } catch (e: unknown) {}
    })();
```

Based on this, my final object will have the following attributes

```
Medical: {
  "documentType": "Medical",
  "notice": "Test",
  "file": 'https://google.ro'
}
```

After that I try to give a for loop in a ScrollView

```
{keys.map((item, idx) => (
                        // @ts-ignore
                        data[item].length > 0 ?
                            (
                                <View key={idx}>
                                    <Center>
                                        <Heading>{item}</Heading>
                                        {
                                            // @ts-ignore
                                            data[item].map((subItem, key) => (
                                                <View key={key}>
                                                    <Box alignItems="center">
                                                        <Box
                                                            rounded="lg"
                                                            overflow="hidden"
                                                            borderColor="coolGray.200"
                                                            borderWidth="1" _dark={{
                                                            borderColor: "coolGray.600",
                                                            backgroundColor: "gray.700"
                                                        }}
                                                            _web={{
                                                                shadow: 2,
                                                                borderWidth: 0
                                                            }}
                                                            _light={{
                                                                backgroundColor: "gray.50"
                                                            }}
                                                        >
                                                            <Stack p="4" space={3}>
                                                                <Stack space={2}>
                                                                    <Center>
                                                                        <Link href="https://nativebase.io">
                                                                            <Icon
                                                                                as={AntDesign}
                                                                                name="eyeo"
                                                                                size="10"
                                                                                color={"red.400"}
                                                                            />
                                                                        </Link>

                                                                    </Center>
                                                                </Stack>
                                                                <Text fontWeight="400">
                                                                    {subItem.notice}
                                                                </Text>
                                                            </Stack>
                                                        </Box>
                                                    </Box>
                                                </View>
                                            ))}
                                    </Center>
                                </View>
                            )
                            :
                            (
                                <View key={idx}></View>
                            )
                    ))}
                </ScrollView>
```

I don't understand exactly why my data is not displayed.. if I give a length on the medical object in that async function, I have data
but here I can't for loop them
Is it a problem of states?
How could I solve it?

Comment: There is a lot that I think is wrong here, but the thing that caught my eye first was the amount of `@ts-ignore`s you are using. I think its a pretty good indicator that you are typing both `data` and the result of your api call incorrectly

Comment: And then data should be a state variable. The async function should called in an `useEffect` with an empty dependency array. Dont do `useEffect(async ()=>{},[])`; do `useEffect(()=>(async ()=>{})(),[])`.

Comment: Also be sure to not directly manipulate `data` when you convert it to a piece of state. State updates are determined by a comparison of the current state and the next; and for objects/arrays, these comparisons can be muddied if you change the current state and try to set the next state to the current state [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly). Or a more in depth [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-react-should-you-mutate-objects/)